# Why mysqld server service gets aborted when i start mysql client service?

Tags: mysql, process

I am installing `mysql-5.5.7rc` from source code. After installation when i start `mysqld` service is being run but as soon as i run `mysql` client service server service gets aborted.. And also `mysql_install_db` is not being installed even after running `mysqld` service running.

Please someone help me..

Comment: Can you please write more Information? Operating system? Have you checked the syslogs?

Comment: belongs on http://serverfault.com

Comment: OS-ubuntu 10.10...
Started mysqld service by `./mysqld --skip-grant` (location /usr/local/mysql/bin)...Now when i run `./mysql` then `mysqld` service gets aborted...

Comment: Unfortunately this question was too vague in it's original form. It should really have been asked on another site, perhaps [ubuntu.se] but it needs a lot more detail if it will get asked again. Therefore, this question is closed as Off Topic.

Comment: MySQL 5.5.8 is the first GA release of MySQL 5.5. I would not trust anything before MySQL 5.5.8. Upgrade to the latest, please.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to stop the mysql server by mysqld stop and then try to start the service.

or user super user authentication to like su command before your command and if password ask enter your ubuntu login password